# Checking for existence of index in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I know how to create indexes

```
CREATE INDEX ix_dsvtable
  ON public."DsVTable"
  USING btree
  (dind, sec, regind, datind);
```

And how can I check if index already exists?

I need to check their existence and create them if they don't exist yet.

Comment: `create index if not exists ...`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can get the list of indexes, their table and column using this query:

```
select
    t.relname as table_name,
    i.relname as index_name,
    a.attname as column_name
from
    pg_class t,
    pg_class i,
    pg_index ix,
    pg_attribute a
where
    t.oid = ix.indrelid
    and i.oid = ix.indexrelid
    and a.attrelid = t.oid
    and a.attnum = ANY(ix.indkey)
    and t.relkind = 'r'
   -- and t.relname like 'mytable'
order by
    t.relname,
    i.relname;
```

From there, you can check existence by index name or involved column(s) and decide to create/skip the index.

Comment: It's work for me. Thanks!

Comment: I also wanted to know if the index was a primary, so I added a condition "and ix.indisprimary = 'f'"

Comment: This query won't print materialized views' indexes... +1 though.