# operator does not exist: `int2vector @> oid` for index query

Tags: postgresql

Given a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test."Op" 
("id" TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
```

I want to create a query to check for the existence of an index. I created a query based off of [Checking for existence of index in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983169/checking-for-existence-of-index-in-postgresql):

```sql
SELECT exists(SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_index WHERE "indkey" @> (
  SELECT "attrelid" FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute WHERE "attrelid" = (
    SELECT "oid" FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE "relname" = 'Op_pkey' AND "relnamespace" = (
      SELECT "oid" FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE "nspname" = 'test'
    )
  )
))
```

but it's currently giving this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: int2vector @> integer
LINE 1: ...exists(SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_index WHERE "indkey" @> (
                                                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 64
```

`pg_catalog.pg_index."indkey"` is a vector but I'm not sure how to construct a query that says `"if any element in the vector matches X"`

Comment: I think the "core" query can be simplified to `select * 
from pg_catalog.pg_index
where indrelid = 'stuff."Op"'::regclass
  and indexrelid = 'stuff."Op_pkey"'::regclass
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the `int2vactor` (which is kind of an internal data type) to an array of `smallint`:

```
... WHERE WHERE indkey::smallint[] @> (...)
```